# Google Map using PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, google-maps

The question is, can I assign a data from the database using PHP ? the longitude and latitude are saved in the database.. thanks :) I'm just a newbie here..

```
      function initialize()
{
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
```

Comment: have you seen [this article in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)?

Comment: You want to replace the `center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),` with coordinates from your DB?

Comment: **What is the difference between server-side and client-side** - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

1) Write a PHP returning the LAT,LNG for a request......

```
 [{ location_id : "x", lat: "51.5", lng : "-0.12"}]
```

2) In javascript (with/without jquery library) make a ajax request to that PHP
and with the LAT,LNG in response initialize the Maps .

```
jQuery.ajax(url: 'php url').done(initMap).fail(renderError) ;
```

Comment: Sir is there a PHP code that can assign the data directly to the latitude and longtitude


   function initialize()
  {
   var mapProp = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng($LAT,$LONG),
     zoom:9,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

Comment: @PjOrtego yes the function is called `json_encode();` in combination with a simple `echo` - refer to php.net

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can pass values from db on ,
->send lat, long in url and assign get value of php to google.maps.LatLng() in jquery.